# How do I highlight the area used by a UserControl in Design View when it does not have a borderstyle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

I've developed a custom UserControl. When I add it to a form in design view, there is no obvious border around it (unless I change the `BorderStyle` property to something other than None).

Some controls (such as PictureBoxes) have a dashed outline to indicate the area they are using. Is there a way to do this for a UserControl?

I'm using C#, .NET 3.5, Windows Forms.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to write a custom designer for your UserControl, which is the same thing that WinForms does for the Panel control. The code in the designer class overrides the [`OnPaintAdornments` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.onpaintadornments.aspx) in order to draw the dashed border around the control's client area.

The easiest way to get started is by inheriting from the `ScrollableControlDesigner` class, which will give you most of the necessary functionality for free. Then add the logic into these methods:

```
public class MyUserControlDesigner : ScrollableControlDesigner
{
   public MyUserControlDesigner()
   {
      base.AutoResizeHandles = true;
   }

   protected override void OnPaintAdornments(PaintEventArgs p)
   {
      // Get the user control that we're designing.
      UserControl component = (UserControl)base.Component;

      // As you mentioned, no reason to draw this border unless the
      // BorderStyle property is set to "None"
      if (component.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
      {
         this.DrawBorder(p.Graphics);
      }

      // Call the base class.
      base.OnPaintAdornments(p);
   }

   protected virtual void DrawBorder(Graphics g)
   {
      // Get the user control that we're designing.
      UserControl component = (UserControl)base.Component;

      // Ensure that the user control we're designing exists and is visible.
      if ((component != null) && component.Visible)
      {
         // Draw the dashed border around the perimeter of its client area.
         using (Pen borderPen = this.BorderPen)
         {
            Rectangle clientRect = this.Control.ClientRectangle;
            clientRect.Width--;
            clientRect.Height--;
            g.DrawRectangle(borderPen, clientRect);
         }
      }
   }

   protected Pen BorderPen
   {
      get
      {
         // Create a Pen object with a color that can be seen on top of
         // the control's background.
         return new Pen((this.Control.BackColor.GetBrightness() < 0.5) ?     
                         ControlPaint.Light(this.Control.BackColor)
                         : ControlPaint.Dark(this.Control.BackColor))
                         { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash };
      }
   }
}
```

Once you've done that, you'll need to instruct your UserControl class to use the custom designer you've written. That's done by adding the [`DesignerAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute.aspx) to its class definition:

```
[Designer(typeof(MyUserControlDesigner)), DesignerCategory("UserControl")]
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    // insert your code here
}
```

And of course, this will require that you add a reference to `System.Design.dll` to your assembly, forcing you to target the **full** version of the .NET Framework (rather than the "Client Profile").

Comment: Full .Net Framework is not required if you assign the Design class by string ref not by typeof. see http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WinFormsCustomCtrl

Comment: Yes, but it's still required on the development machine. I've done exactly what's described in that article before, but it's a giant pain in the rear. And hardly worth it: the Client Profile isn't that much smaller than the full framework.

Comment: The development machine should always have the the full .net framework. And the Design class is only for developers :) But if you write an application for anybody you force them to install the full .net framework if they only have the client profile.